# jQuery only works on first screen

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following dropdown that works fine with my jquery on the first screen its produced but the same screen can be produced more than one times and subsequent pages the jQuery doesn't work for showing the other box.

I'm puzzled now. Any help much appreciated.

```
<xsl:for-each select="bankguarantees/bankguaranteedata">
    <div id="panel22" class="panels">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">panel22_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%"  bgcolor="#CECFFF" style="border-top: none" cellspacing="10">    
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="lightyellow" class="inline">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="Header" height="1"></td>
</tr>


   <tr name="contliab" id="contliab">
            <script type="text/javascript">
             $('#producttypes').change(function()
             {
               if($('#otherprodtype').is(':selected'))
               {
               $('#otherprodtypebox').show();
               }
             else
              {
               if($('#otherprodtypebox').is(':visible'))
               {
                 $('#otherprodtypebox').hide();
               }
              }
             });;
            </script>
            <td class="Label">Product Type</td>
            <td class="field">
             <select name="producttypes" id="producttypes">
              <option value="interventionguar">
               <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='interventionguar']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
               </xsl:if>Intervention Guarantee</option>
              <option value="customsguar">
               <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='customsguar']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
              </xsl:if>Customs Guarantee</option>
              <option value="otherprodtype" id="otherprodtype">
               <xsl:if test="producttypes/option[@id='otherprodtype']='selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected"/>
               </xsl:if>Other</option>
             </select>
             <input class="amdInputText" type="text" id="otherprodtypebox" value="" style="display:none;">
                <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="otherprodtypebox"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute></input>
            </td>
           </tr>
```

Comment: Have you included references to jQuery only on the first page?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'll double check but they should all be in the one file. Its the same panel reused

Comment: no errors in firebug console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$('#producttypes')` is an element that is dynamically added after the page has loaded (from an AJAX call for example), then you'll have to use `delegate()` in order to catch events coming from it.

```
$("#parentElement").delegate('#producttypes','change',function(){
  ...
});
```

The delegate function is placed on the parent of the dynamic element. The parent element doesn't have to be a direct ancestor, it can also be `$('body')` but you should avoid attaching all of your events to the body for performance reasons.

> [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)  -
>
> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: @j08 - I still have some issues with dynamic elements and the `on()` function in 1.8... These problems always /disappear after changing to delegate...

Comment: Never had any issues using on() myself with dynamic or static elements. Have you reported any bugs you've found?

Comment: @j08 - nope. I'm usually just so relieved to get it working and then move on to the next thing :P

Comment: Thanks @Lix . Its basically I want the user to be able to have the box show up when they select other on each screen and they can enter a different value in each box.

Comment: @Lix I've tried your code but it didn't work. I have added code to my question. You can see new panels are created depending on the amount the user select so we can have panel22_0 , panel22_1 etc. My code works for panel22_0 but not for any thereafter

Comment: @Lix I'm afraid it din't work. I tried $('body').delegate('#producttypes','change',function()